# Can't add a reference in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I got a problem while adding a reference in a C# project.

I want to add `hLib.dll` to my project, so I right click on my project name -> add reference -> browse it and add it.

But when I go and write "using hLib;"  I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'hLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
 ###FIXED###
Thanks for your help!
```

Comment: the name of the DLL can be independent of the namespaces inside

Comment: Are you sure that the DLL contains a namespace called hLib?

Comment: The target version for .net might be different between your project and the lib. Please check!

Comment: Run the DLL through a reflector, see if it depends on other DLL's and add them as well.

Comment: oh, the namespace of it was MLibrary.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

In the Solution explorer under the project, expand the References node and double click on hLib. That will open the object browser where you can see what the actual namespaces in the dll are.

From there you can see what to put in the `using` statement

Answer (score 1):

Find the `Object Browser` by opening the solution explorer, and right clicking *references > hLib.dll*

You can then look into it to find the namespace, classes and other objects.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using Visual Studio 2017; error message (see image below) when trying to "add a reference" to a project. The issue was resolved by uninstalling a previous version of Visual Studio (2012) installed in my computer.
 [ResourceManagerPackage error windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkyBF.png)